# Attachments management

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm building a system where a `Meeting` can have zero or more `Attachment`s.
To avoid loading the whole attachment binary each time I load a `Meeting`, I have an `AttachmentRef(size, mimetype, reference, name, hash)`.

This reference is created via a factory that guess the `mimetype`, compute the `hash` and `size` and esnure that everything is saved aside of the binary content : `AttachmentsFactory.create(name, byte[]):AttachmentRef`.

Then, when the user want to retrieve an attachment it has to dereference the reference. The `Attachment` is more or less the same as a reference except that it has the binary content `Attachment(size, mimetype, name, content)` (Itw ill be implemented with a composition of reference and byte[]).

My question is about the retrieval of this attachmeent, I have two main possibilities and I would like to knwo which one looks best in a "DDD" design ?

**1 - Dumb reference, smart service**

```
AttachementService {
  dereference(ref):Attachment {
    // Get the binary, recompute and verify the hash and return an Attachment
  }
}

attachmentService.dereference(ref)
```

**2 - Smart reference, dumb service**

```
AttachmentService {
    read(ref):byte[] {
       // Just return the content for the ref
    }
}

AttachmentReference {
    dereference(attachmentService) {
        content = attachmentService.read(this)
        // recompute and verify the hash
        return new Attachment(this, content)
    }
}

ref.dereference(attachmentService)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a pretty good example of interactions between *Bounded Contexts*.

If your `Meeting` is in one BC and your content is in the `Content` BC then you could very well have the physically attached content (`byte[]`) represented as a *Value Object* in your `Meeting` as you have done with your reference.

The attached content may be represented as a `ContentItem` or some such in your `Content` BC and in that it would be an *Aggregate Root*.

The retrieval of the actual content would typically occur on the integration/application layer.  No need to have that in the `Meeting` BC as it wouldn't do much, I assume.

Comment: Okay thanks; That is more or less what I had in mind. But to return the content of an attachment, I have to verify that his hash is unchanged. Is that the responsibility of the `AttachmentRef` or the application layer ? Actually, it is the `AttachmentFactory` that compute the hash and build the `AttachmentRef` but ideally the algorithm must be the same (code) so where should I put it ?

Comment: I'd place that processing in the application/integration layer.  When you initially store the attachment you'd need to compute the hash and it is associated with the attachment.  You may even want to add an algorithm name to the attachment (or do that later when wanting to change algorithms).  Then when you retrieve the content your, say, `ContentService` would have the hashing algorithm injected (or the algorithm container).  It could then return the result from a fetch and the result can indicate whether the hash was a match; else throw an exception if it doesn't match and becomes ops issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eben